# Getting a runtime error while passing a function

Tags: c++

I am writing a function that takes an integer "size" as input and returns a 2d vector which is filled spirally from 1 to size*size. So, I created 4 additional functions to traverse left, right, bottom and top. All functions are working correctly except bottom function. Here, i am providing a part of the whole code that is necessary to resolve the problem.

Error :- Your submission stopped because of a runtime error. ex: division by 
          zero, array index out of bounds, uncaught exception.

I am getting a runtime error when i am passing a "right" function and a "bottom" function. The problem is in the function but I am unable to resolve it. The right function is passing smoothly but the problem is with the bottom function.

```
void right(vector<vector<int>> &A,int &row,int &column,int &total_elements,int size)
{
    if(total_elements==0) return;
    while(A[row][column]==INT_MIN && column<size)
    {
        A[row][column]=1+A[row][column-1];
        column++;
        total_elements--;
    }
    column--;
    return;
}

void bottom(vector<vector<int>> &A,int &row,int &column,int &total_elements,int size)
{
    if(total_elements==0) return;
    while(A[row][column]==INT_MIN && row<l)
    {
        A[row][column]=1+A[row-1][column];
        row++;
        total_elements--;
    }
    row--;
    return;
}

vector<vector<int> > Solution::generateMatrix(int size) {
    int total_elements=size*size;
    vector< vector <int> > arr(size, vector <int> (size, INT_MIN));
    arr[0][0]=1;total_elements-=1;
    int row=0;
    int column=1;

    right(arr,row,column,total_elements,size);
    row++;

    bottom(arr,row,column,total_elements,size);
    column--;
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting? please update the question with that

Comment: Your submission stopped because of a runtime error. ex: division by zero, array index out of bounds, uncaught exception.

Comment: `A[i-1]` uses a negative index (as `i` starts at 0), which is *undefined behavior* - I'm really not sure what you are trying to do here

Comment: @UnholySheep Not that simple because `i` is incremented before `bottom` is called. But I agree the code is **completely** obscure.

Comment: Even if in that line I change A[i][j]=1+A[i-1][j] to A[i][j]=5 , i am getting the same error

Comment: @anitashrivastava It's not a good idea to use one letter variable names. Apart from anything else it means that it's hard for anyone to help you because it's hard for anyone to understand the code.

Comment: @anitashrivastava How big is `A` when you get this problem?

Comment: Is this from those competitive programming sites? If so, they are probably not the best way to learn programming.

Comment: A=2. And i have made all the necessary changes to better understand the issue.